# pickerview missing in xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview, watchos

I'm trying to create a apple watch app, but i'm using xcode 6.4 and I need the pickerview control but that control is missing.

ps. In xcode 7 beta that control exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ive not checked myself whether its moved or something, but - cant you open your project in XCode 7, add the pickerview, then close it and open it again in 6.4?  The pickerview should still be there.

Comment: PickerViews are definitely available in XCode 6.4, Ive just checked.

Comment: No, PickerViews aren't available in XCode 6.4.